# Extracting cells from struct in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code in Matlab

```
for h=1:2
    B=randn(3,2);
    C=randn(3,2);
    A={B C}; 
    baseA_.A=A;
    eval(['baseA.A' num2str(h) '= baseA_;'])
end

clearvars -except baseA
```

Now in each iteration `h` of a loop I want to extract the `1x2` cell inside the struct `Ah`.

I have tried

```
for h=1:2
    indA=sprintf('A%d', h); 
    Acell = struct2cell(baseA.(indA));

end
```

but `Acell` is a `1x1` cell containing a `1x2` cell. I want directly `Acell` equal to the `1x2` cell. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the second loop as follows:

```
for h=1:2
    indA=sprintf('A%d', h); 
    Acell = baseA.(indA).A;

end
```

At each iteration Acell will be overwritten but I'assume you posted only a part of the loop code.

Moreover, by using the same approach you've used in the second loop, you can avoid using `eval` replacing that line of code with:

```
%eval(['baseA.A' num2str(h) '= baseA_;'])
indA=sprintf('A%d', h)
baseA.(indA)=baseA_;
```

Hope this helps.